# Can't access public methods of C++/CLI wrapper class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli

I have written a Wrapper assembly in C++/CLI. Now I want to call into C++/CLI from C#,however I get the error:

```
Error CS0122  'USBWrapper.setPortDisable(int)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

So my .h and .cpp file are as follows(which is compiled with the /clr switch):

**The .h file:**

```
// USBFunctionsWrapper.h

#pragma once

#include "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\brainstem_dev_kit_win32_i386_17\brainstem_dev_kit_win32_i386\development\lib\BrainStem2\BrainStem-all.h"
#include "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\brainstem_dev_kit_win32_i386_17\brainstem_dev_kit_win32_i386\development\lib\BrainStem2\aUSBHub2x4.h"

using namespace System;

namespace USBFunctionsWrapper {

public ref class USBWrapper
{
    public:
        USBWrapper();
        ~USBWrapper();
        aErr setPortDisable(int portNumber);
        aErr setPortEnable(int portNumber);
        aErr usbSleep(int time);
    private:
};
}
```

**The .cpp file:**

```
// This is the main DLL file.
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "USBFunctionsWrapper.h"

#include "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\brainstem_dev_kit_win32_i386_17\brainstem_dev_kit_win32_i386\development\lib\BrainStem2\BrainStem-all.h"
#include "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\brainstem_dev_kit_win32_i386_17\brainstem_dev_kit_win32_i386\development\lib\BrainStem2\aUSBHub2x4.h"
aUSBHub2x4 stem;
aErr err = aErrNone;
USBFunctionsWrapper::USBWrapper::USBWrapper() {
    err = stem.linkDiscoverAndConnect(USB);
}
USBFunctionsWrapper::USBWrapper::~USBWrapper() {
    err = stem.linkDisconnect();
}
aErr USBFunctionsWrapper::USBWrapper::setPortDisable(int portNumber) {
    return stem.usb.setPortDisable(portNumber);
}

aErr USBFunctionsWrapper::USBWrapper::setPortEnable(int portNumber) {
    return stem.usb.setPortEnable(portNumber);
}

aErr USBFunctionsWrapper::USBWrapper::usbSleep(int time) {
    return aTime_MSSleep(time);
}
```

**The C# file I am calling these functions from:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using USBFunctionsWrapper;

namespace USBPortWrapper
{
    public class WrapperClass
    {
        USBWrapper usb;
        public WrapperClass()
        {
            usb = new USBWrapper();
        }

        public void setPortEnable(int portNumber)
        {
            usb.setPortEnable(portNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error for the `usb.setPortEnable(portNumber)` function in the c# code.
Do you know what could be a possible reason for that?

Comment: Can you see any of the public members of your CLI class in C#?

Comment: Yes I can see all members,even the method that C# objects that it is not accessible . :/

Comment: Also what is `aErr`? Have you created a wrapper for it?

Comment: aErr is basically an enumerator that has all the error codes of the hardware that I am going to use.details of the hardware:
https://acroname.com/products/s77-usbhub-2x4-0?sku=S77-USBHUB-2X4
 No I haven't created a wrapper for it, I have referenced it from a .h file.

Comment: Although I have got little CLI experience, my gut feeling is that creating a managed wrapper for `aErr` should solve this for you.

Comment: Plus make sure you're compiling your C++ project with `/clr` parameter (which can also be set through project properties dialog).

Comment: Thank you very much,that solved the problem, although i did not wrap the aErr, just tried to remove it from return statements for the time being,and the problem dissapeared ,hence by wrapping aErr the problem should be solved, Thank you a lot.